# database created on emulator but not on device

Tags: android

in the following class i have created methods to create and manipulate the database

```
package com.ashish.testquiz2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class QuestionAdapter {

static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_OPTION1 = "option1";
static final String KEY_OPTION2 = "option2";
static final String KEY_OPTION3 = "option3";
static final String KEY_OPTION4 = "option4";
static final String KEY_QUE = "question";
static final String KEY_ANS = "answer";
static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quizdb2";
static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "quiztb2";
static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " 
(" + KEY_ID + " integer(10) not null primary key, " + KEY_QUE + " 
varchar(150) not null, " + KEY_OPTION1 + " varchar(50) not null, " + 
KEY_OPTION2 + " varchar(50) not null, " + KEY_OPTION3 + " varchar(50) not 
null, " + KEY_OPTION4 + " varchar(50) not null," + KEY_ANS + " varchar(50) 
not null);";

final Context context;

DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

public QuestionAdapter(Context ctx){
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

}

public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        //db.execSQL("drop table if already exists " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        //db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
        Log.w(TAG, "upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to 
version " + newVersion + " which will destroy all old data");
        //db.execSQL("drop table if already exists " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}

//opens the database
public QuestionAdapter open() throws Exception{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//closes the database
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}

//insert into database
public void insertitem() {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("drop table " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    String sql1 = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " , " + 
KEY_QUE + " , " + KEY_OPTION1 + " , " + KEY_OPTION2 + " , " + KEY_OPTION3 + 
" , " + KEY_OPTION4 + " , " + KEY_ANS + 
            " ) values(1,'Nobel prize is awarded for which of the following 
disciplines:', 'Literature,Peace and Economics','Medicine and 
Physiology','Chemistry and Physics','All of the above','All of the 
above');";

    String sql2 = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " , " + 
KEY_QUE + " , " + KEY_OPTION1 + " , " + KEY_OPTION2 + " , " + KEY_OPTION3 + 
" , " + KEY_OPTION4 + " , " + KEY_ANS + 
            " ) values(2,'Galileo was an astronomer who:', 'developed the 
telescope','discovered four satellites of Jupiter','discovered that the 
movement of pendulum produces a regular time interval','All of the 
above','discovered four satellites of Jupiter');";

    String sql3 = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " , " + 
KEY_QUE + " , " + KEY_OPTION1 + " , " + KEY_OPTION2 + " , " + KEY_OPTION3 + 
" , " + KEY_OPTION4 + " , " + KEY_ANS + 
            " ) values(3,'Who is the father of geometry:', 
'Aristotle','Euclid','Pythagoras','Kepler','Euclid');";

    String sql4 = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " , " + 
KEY_QUE + " , " + KEY_OPTION1 + " , " + KEY_OPTION2 + " , " + KEY_OPTION3 + 
" , " + KEY_OPTION4 + " , " + KEY_ANS + 
            " ) values(4,'Who is popularly called as Iron Man of India:', 
'Subhash Chandra Bose','Sardar Vallabhai Patel','Tony Stark','Govind Vallabh 
Pant','Sardar Vallabhai Patel');";

    String sql5 = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " , " + 
KEY_QUE + " , " + KEY_OPTION1 + " , " + KEY_OPTION2 + " , " + KEY_OPTION3 + 
" , " + KEY_OPTION4 + " , " + KEY_ANS + 
            " ) values(5,'Ball-point pen, used in day-to-day life was 
invented by:', 'Waterman brothers','Write brothers','Biro brothers','Bicc 
brothers','Biro brothers');";

    String sql6 = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " , " + 
KEY_QUE + " , " + KEY_OPTION1 + " , " + KEY_OPTION2 + " , " + KEY_OPTION3 + 
" , " + KEY_OPTION4 + " , " + KEY_ANS + 
            " ) values(6,'The metal whose salts are sensitive to light is:', 
'Zinc','Silver','Copper','Aluminium','Silver');";

    String sql7 = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " , " + 
KEY_QUE + " , " + KEY_OPTION1 + " , " + KEY_OPTION2 + " , " + KEY_OPTION3 + 
" , " + KEY_OPTION4 + " , " + KEY_ANS + 
            " ) values(7,'Worlds largest desert is:', 
'Thar','Kalahari','Sahara','Sonoran','Sahara');";

    String sql8 = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " , " + 
 KEY_QUE + " , " + KEY_OPTION1 + " , " + KEY_OPTION2 + " , " + KEY_OPTION3 + 
" , " + KEY_OPTION4 + " , " + KEY_ANS + 
            " ) values(8,'Black soil is best suited foe the cultivation 
of:', 'Cotton','Rice','Cereals','Sugarcane','Cotton');";

    String sql9 = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " , " + 
KEY_QUE + " , " + KEY_OPTION1 + " , " + KEY_OPTION2 + " , " + KEY_OPTION3 + 
" , " + KEY_OPTION4 + " , " + KEY_ANS + 
            " ) values(9,'The first chairman of Atomic Energy Comission 
was:', 'Dr. C.V. Raman','Dr. H.J. Bhabha','Dr. A.P.J. Abdul Kalam','Dr. 
Vikram Sarabhai','Dr. H.J. Bhabha');";

    String sql10 = "insert into " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ID + " , " + 
KEY_QUE + " , " + KEY_OPTION1 + " , " + KEY_OPTION2 + " , " + KEY_OPTION3 + 
" , " + KEY_OPTION4 + " , " + KEY_ANS + 
            " ) values(10,'Which is considered the biggest port of India:', 
'Kolkata','Coachin','Chennai','Mumbai','Mumbai');";


    try {
        Log.i("sql1", sql1);
        Log.i("sql2", sql2);
        db.execSQL(sql1);
        db.execSQL(sql2);
        db.execSQL(sql3);
        db.execSQL(sql4);
        db.execSQL(sql5);
        db.execSQL(sql6);
        db.execSQL(sql7);
        db.execSQL(sql8);
        db.execSQL(sql9);
        db.execSQL(sql10);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//retrieve question
public Cursor getQuestion() {
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ID,KEY_QUE, 
KEY_OPTION1, KEY_OPTION2, KEY_OPTION3, KEY_OPTION4, KEY_ANS}, null, null, 
null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return cursor;

}

//retrieve first question
public Cursor getFirstQue() throws Exception{
    Cursor cursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] 
{KEY_ID,KEY_QUE, KEY_OPTION1, KEY_OPTION2, KEY_OPTION3, KEY_OPTION4, 
KEY_ANS}, KEY_ID + " = 1", null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}


}
```

i have dropped the table and created it again in the insert method because it wasn't working before. with the above code it works on the emulator but not on the device.
the above code is used in the following class

```
    package com.ashish.testquiz2;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class NewActivity extends Activity{

    TextView tvNextQue;
    RadioGroup rg1;
    RadioButton rbOption1,rbOption2,rbOption3,rbOption4;
    Button bNextQue,bPreQue;

    QuestionAdapter qa;
    Cursor cur = null;
    Cursor cur1 = null;

    int score =0,id;
    String answer = "";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newactivity);

        tvNextQue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNextQue);
        rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        rbOption1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbOption1);
        rbOption2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbOption2);
        rbOption3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbOption3);
        rbOption4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbOption4);
        bNextQue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNextQue);
        bPreQue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPreQue);
        qa = new QuestionAdapter(NewActivity.this);

        try {
            qa.open();
            cur1 = qa.getFirstQue();
            cur1.moveToNext();

            tvNextQue.setText("Q. " + 
    cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("question")));
            rbOption1.setText("" + 
    cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("option1")));
            rbOption2.setText("" + 
    cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("option2")));
            rbOption3.setText("" + 
    cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("option3")));
            rbOption4.setText("" + 
    cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("option4")));
            id = cur1.getInt(cur1.getColumnIndex("id"));
            answer = cur1.getString(cur1.getColumnIndex("answer"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cur1.close();

        try {
            qa.open();
            cur = qa.getQuestion();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cur.moveToPosition(1);

        bNextQue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(!cur.isAfterLast()){

                    tvNextQue.setText("Q. " + 
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("question")));
                    rbOption1.setText("" + 
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("option1")));
                    rbOption2.setText("" + 
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("option2")));
                    rbOption3.setText("" + 
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("option3")));
                    rbOption4.setText("" + 
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("option4")));
                    id = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("id"));
                    answer = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("answer"));
                    cur.moveToNext();

                    rbOption1.setChecked(false);
                    rbOption2.setChecked(false);
                    rbOption3.setChecked(false);
                    rbOption4.setChecked(false);
                }
                else {
                    Intent i = new Intent(NewActivity.this, 
    EndActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("score", score);
                    startActivity(i);


                }
                qa.close();
            }

        });

        rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int id) {

                if(rbOption1.isChecked() || rbOption2.isChecked() || 
    rbOption3.isChecked() || rbOption4.isChecked()){
                    String ans = "";
                    switch (id) {
                    case R.id.rbOption1:
                        ans = rbOption1.getText().toString();
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbOption2:
                        ans = rbOption2.getText().toString();
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbOption3:
                        ans = rbOption3.getText().toString();
                        break;
                    case R.id.rbOption4:
                        ans = rbOption4.getText().toString();
                        break;

                    //default:
                        //break;
                    }
                    if(ans.equals(answer)){
                        score++;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(NewActivity.this, ans, 
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(NewActivity.this, answer, 
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        bPreQue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!cur.isBeforeFirst()){

                    tvNextQue.setText("Q. " + 
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("question")));
                    rbOption1.setText("" + 
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("option1")));
                    rbOption2.setText("" + 
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("option2")));
                    rbOption3.setText("" + 
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("option3")));
                    rbOption4.setText("" + 
    cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("option4")));
                    id = cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("id"));
                    answer = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("answer"));
                    cur.moveToPrevious();
                }
            }
        });
      }
    }
```

I think somehow database is not created in the device.(just an opinion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have altered the schema of the table(s), you must uninstall the app from your device/emulator and rerun so the db will be recreated.  
Then the `onCreate()` of the database class will be executed and create the table(s).  
 So you must include in `onCreate()` of the database helper class all the necessary statements.

Comment: i haven't altered the schema of the tables, i have uninstalled and reinstalled but it just doesn't work

Comment: Your `onCreate()` is empty so the tables are not created.